# For Loop and Multiple Commands in .bashrc

Tags: bash, terminal, command, git-bash

I'm looking for a way to run two commands with a for loop as an alias in my .bashrc. Currently I have this:

`alias finpeg="mkdir outdir; for i in *.mp4; do (ffmpeg -i %i -ar 22050 outdir/$i; done"`

Running these commands separately in the terminal works fine but I can't seem to get it to work as an alias. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: Use a function instead and all your problems will go away..., See `help function` and try `LESS=+/Shell\ Function\ Definitions man bash`

Comment: In addition to using a function instead of an alias, you also need to remove the stray open-parenthesis, use `"$i"` instead of `%i`, and should also double-quote the other variable reference (`"outdir/$i" instead of just `outdir/$i`) to avoid trouble with spaces in filenames.

Comment: Perfect this all worked thanks!

Comment: Just quickly can I do `for i in *.mp4 or *.mkv` ?

Comment: `*.{mp4,mkv}` ?

Comment: Note that `$i` will be replaced by the conten of the variable `i` by the time the alias is defined, not when it's executed. See [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-single-vs-double-quotes). BTW, you can spot the source of your problem, by turning on `set -x` when running the alias.

Comment: Just about the only legitimate reason to use aliases is to add options to every use of a command, e.g. `alias ls='ls -l'`.